# Add n tasks to celery queue and wait for the results

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I'd add several jobs to the celery queue and wait for the results. I have many ideas about how I would accomplish this using some type of shared storage (memcached, redis, database, etc.), but I think it was something Celery could handle automatically, but I can't find any resources online.

**Code example**

```
def do_tasks(b):
    for a in b:
        c.delay(a)

    return c.all_results_some_how()
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

For **Celery >= 3.0**, TaskSet is [deprecated](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.0/internals/deprecation.html#taskset) in favour of [group](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#groups).

```
from celery import group
from tasks import add

job = group([
             add.s(2, 2),
             add.s(4, 4),
             add.s(8, 8),
             add.s(16, 16),
             add.s(32, 32),
])
```

Start the group in the background:

```
result = job.apply_async()
```

Wait:

```
result.join()
```

Comment: Information about `.s()` can be found [in the `celery.Signature` docs, here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.Signature)

Answer (score 15):

[`Task.delay`](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.delay) returns [`AsyncResult`](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult). Use [`AsyncResult.get`](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult.get) to get result of each task.

To do that you need to keep references to the tasks.

```
def do_tasks(b):
    tasks = []
    for a in b:
        tasks.append(c.delay(a))
    return [t.get() for t in tasks]
```

Or you can use [`ResultSet`](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.ResultSet):

**UPDATE**: `ResultSet` is deprecated, please see [@laffuste 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686850/add-n-tasks-to-celery-queue-and-wait-for-the-results/36466097#36466097).

```
def do_tasks(b):
    rs = ResultSet([])
    for a in b:
        rs.add(c.delay(a))
    return rs.get()
```

Comment: Worked like a charm save `ResultSet` requiring a list of results (or empty list) in it's constructor. I submitted an edit to the post to correct it.

Comment: @Prydie, Thank you for your feedback and correction.

Answer (score 2):

I have a hunch you are not really wanting the delay but the async feature of Celery.

I think you really want a [TaskSet](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/next/userguide/tasksets.html#id3):

```
from celery.task.sets import TaskSet
from someapp.tasks import sometask

def do_tasks(b):
    job = TaskSet([sometask.subtask((a,)) for a in b])
    result = job.apply_async()
    # might want to handle result.successful() == False
    return result.join()
```