# Celery Async Feature

Tags: python, celery

I have a task that I would like to run every hour. I need to run it 3 times (for every element in list) but instead of having them run one after another I would like them to run all at once. How is this possible with Celery? I am using Flask as well.

Right now, I have a file called tasks.py with my tasks, and I use a celerybeat schedule to run every hour.

This is the function I call every hour:

Note that I am calling a function I import into the file.

```
@celery.task
def stats():
    list = [1,2,3] 

    functions = [sensor_stats(60, each) for each in list]
    results = [function.wait() for function in functions]
```

**Update:**
I defined a new task, that would loop through the list and create a group that would call the stats task for each list element, that way each one is running in parallel.

See http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.group for more info

It looked something like this:

```
@celery.task
def stats(interval, f_id):
     sensor_stats(interval, f_id)

 @celery.task
 def sensor_statistics():
    list = [1,2,3]

    res = group
    group(stats_function.s(60, each) for each in list)()

 CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
     'Stat Script': {
         'task': 'tasks2.sensor_statistics',
         'schedule': timedelta(hours=1),
         'args': (),
     }
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add n tasks to celery queue and wait for the results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686850/add-n-tasks-to-celery-queue-and-wait-for-the-results)