# Can you run multiple Flask SQLAlchemy queries in parallel?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, uwsgi

In my current setup, if I do five 100ms queries, they take 500ms total. Is there a way I can run them in parallel so it only takes 100ms?

I'm running Flask behind nginx/uwsgi, but can change any of that.

Specifically, I'd like to be able to turn code from this:

```
result_1 = db.session.query(...).all()
result_2 = db.session.query(...).all()
result_3 = db.session.query(...).all()
```

To something like this:

```
result_1, result_2, result_3 = run_in_parallel([
  db.session.query(...).all(),
  db.session.query(...).all(),
  db.session.query(...).all(),
])
```

Is there a way to do that with Flask and SQLAlchemy?

Comment: Aside: Looks like this could also possibly be done using celery per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686850/add-n-tasks-to-celery-queue-and-wait-for-the-results

I'm also wondering, whether using threads, celery, or something else, whether solutions have some "connect to the database" or "shared connection to the database" overhead

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Parallelism in general

In general, if you want to run tasks in parallel you can use threads or processes. In python, threads are great for tasks that are I/O bound (meaning the time they take is spent waiting on another resource - waiting for your database, or for the disk, or for a remote webserver), and processes are great for tasks that are CPU bound (math and other computationally intensive tasks).

### concurrent.futures

In your case, threads are ideal. Python has a [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) module that you can look into, but there's a fair bit to unpack: safely using threads usually means limiting the number of threads that can be run by using a pool of threads and a queue for tasks. For that reason I much prefer [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) library, which provides wrappers around `threading` to give you an easy to use interface and to handle a lot of the complexity for you.

When using `concurrent.futures`, you create an executor, and then you submit tasks to it along with a list of arguments. Instead of calling a function like this:

```
# get 4 to the power of 5
result = pow(4, 5)
print(result)
```

You submit the function, and its arguments:

You would normally use concurrent.futures a bit like this:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()
future = executor.submit(pow, 4, 5)
print(future.result())
```

Notice how we don't call the function by using `pow()`, we submit the function object `pow` which the executor will call inside a thread.

To make it easier to use the `concurrent.futures` library with Flask, you can use [flask-executor](https://github.com/dchevell/flask-executor) which works like any other Flask extension. It also handles the edge cases where your background tasks require access to Flask's context locals (like the `app`, `session`, `g` or `request` objects) inside a background task. Full disclosure: I wrote and maintain this library.

(Fun fact: `concurrent.futures` wraps both threading and multiprocessing, using the same API - so if you find yourself needing multiprocessing for CPU bound tasks in future, you can use the same library in the same way to achieve your goal)

### Putting it all together

Here's what using `flask-executor` to run SQLAlchemy tasks in parallel looks like:

```
from flask_executor import Executor
# ... define your `app` and `db` objects

executor = Executor(app)   

# run the same query three times in parallel and collect all the results
futures = []
for i in range(3):
    # note the lack of () after ".all", as we're passing the function object, not calling it ourselves
    future = executor.submit(db.session.query(MyModel).all) 
    futures.append(future)

for future in futures:
    print(future.result())
```

Boom, you have now run multiple Flask SQLAlchemy queries in parallel.

Comment: If you're reading this and want to actually issue a function call which in turn runs SQLAlchemy queries, it'll work fine even with parameters - just pass them as `*args` or `*kwargs` (comma-separated): `executor.submit(my_function_object, param_one, param_two)`

Comment: Can’t you have issues due to using the same database session in all threads?